# How can anisotropic kernels for Gaussian process regression be used with a variable number of features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My use case is, that I want to have automatic feature selection for Gaussian process regression. For isotropic kernels, this can be done easily, as shown in the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

X = np.random.rand(100, 10)
y = np.random.rand(100)

gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=RBF(length_scale=[1]))
selector = SequentialFeatureSelector(gpr, forward=False)
selector.fit(X, y)
```

In order to use anisotropic kernels, one would have to change the definition of the kernel to `RBF(length_scale=[1] * num_features)`.

However, the number of features changes in each round of the feature selection, which raises `ValueError: Anisotropic kernel must have the same number of dimensions as data (10!=9)`

Is there any way to get an anisotropic kernel with a dynamic number of features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a dirty hack I subclassed `GaussianProcessRegressor` and added a function to `fit` that recursively scans all the kernels and replaces the length_scale parameter of all kernels that can be anisotropic (currently only RBF and Matern) with a vector.

```
class GaussianProcessRegressorAnisotropic(GaussianProcessRegressor):
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self._fix_kernel_length_scales(self.kernel, X.shape[1])
        super().fit(X, y)

    def _fix_kernel_length_scales(self, kernel, num_features):
        if isinstance(kernel, RBF) or isinstance(kernel, Matern):
            kernel.length_scale = [kernel.length_scale] * num_features
        elif isinstance(kernel, Product) or isinstance(kernel, Sum):
            self._fix_kernel_length_scales(kernel.k1, num_features)
            self._fix_kernel_length_scales(kernel.k2, num_features)
        elif isinstance(kernel, Exponentiation):
            self._fix_kernel_length_scales(kernel.kernel, num_features)
        elif isinstance(kernel, CompoundKernel):
            for sub_kernel in kernel.kernels:
                self._fix_kernel_length_scales(sub_kernel, num_features)
```

But maybe anyone has a nicer solution?